# join two un-sorted txt files in unix

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, join

I have two files, say:

FILE1

```
size  freq
  1   .4
  2   .8
  8   .3
  40   .2
  90   .1
```

And FILE2

```
size  freq
  1  .2
  3  .5
  4  .1
  60  .3
  70  .2
```

I like to join then in a way so, the results would be like:

```
    size  freq1  freq2
      1  .4  .2
      2  .8   0
      3   0  .5
      8   0   0
      40  .2  0
      60  0  .3
      70  0  .2
      90  .1  0
```

I used

```
join -a 1 -a 2 -e "0" -o '0,1.2,2.2' FILE1 FILE2
```

But it sorts the lines one-by-one from either files. Is there any way to join and sort the results simultaneously?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The output is fine with my `join (GNU coreutils) 8.20`.

Comment: My output is fine, too.

Comment: Also fine with join V 8.13 (Ubuntu 12.04).  Maybe you'd like to tell us your version of `join` and what your observed output is?

Comment: Sorry, bad explanation. The actual files are much larger and then more complicated. I edit

Answer (score 0):

Note join doesn't support the same key selection and comparison functions as sort(1) (yet).
Therefore the data must be sorted using sort in a specific way so as to be acceptable for join(1). Specifically in this case, join(1) does not currently support numeric comparison.
One can avoid this issue while keeping "numeric" order by using a fixed width numeric field (with leading zeros), or if strict numeric order isn't an issue you can get sort to operate like join operates by default by previously sorting with: sort -k 1b,1 (that's documented in the join man page).